# Get the presenting viewController of viewController.view in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, viewcontroller

i am trying to get the presenting viewController of a viewController's view 
The idea is like that :
i have a

`viewController = CategoriesViewController`

and i am presenting its view inside anther

`viewController = HomeViewController`

by using

`CategoriesViewController.view`
so when i want to reach the

`HomeViewController` from `CategoriesViewController`

i do this

`let vc = self.presentingViewController as? HomeViewController`

but it is telling me that it is nil
i tried the

`.parentViewController`

and it is returning

`CategoriesViewController`

Comment: can you explain more clearly the relationship between `CategoriesViewController` and `HomeViewController`, and the desired result?

Comment: ```HomeViewController``` has an instance of ```CategoriesViewController```
and i am presenting the view of ```CategoriesViewController``` from ```HomeViewController```
the thing is that I want to reach ```HomeViewController``` from ```CategoriesViewController```
for example, ihave a variable in ```HomeViewController``` i want to change its value

Comment: @Sweeper ......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you want to change a variable in `HomeVieController` using `CategoriesViewController` you could create your own [protocol](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Protocols.html). You can use protocols to communicate between different controllers.

```
    protocol ChangeVariableProtocol {
            func changeVar(variable: Int)
        }
```

In the protocol itself you only declare methods.
In your `CategoriesViewController` you would create a delegate Varibale like this

`var changeVarDelegate: ChangeVariableProtocl?`

Whenever you want to change the variable in `CategoriesViewController` you call your protocol method.

`changeVarDelegate?.changeVar(10)`

In HomeViewController you need to implement this protocol and initialize the changeVarDelegate variable.

```
    extension HomeViewController: ChangeVarProtocol {
        func changeVar(var: variable) {
           // Implement your own logic here
         self.valueToChange = variable
        }
```

And make sure that you initialize `changeVarDelegate` when you are instancing your `CategoriesViewController`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yea thanks I did use the delegates to access ```HomeViewController```

Answer (score 0):

- Create a callback closure property both in `CategoriesViewController` and in its view.
- Right before presenting the controller assign the closure to *change the value of a property* to the callback property in the controller.
- In `viewDidLoad` hand the closure over to the view.
- Call the closure in the view to be executed in the presenting controller.

Comment: Thanks 
I used delegates and solved the problem. <3